# WP heartbeat for Laravel Nova?

Tags: php, wordpress, laravel-nova, heartbeat

WP heartbeat for Laravel Nova??

I need the option to lock a resource when someone opens it for edit.

So, like with WP heartbeat, that makes sure only one is using the resource.

Laravel Nova have the “Preventing Conflicts” functionality, but that does not prevent another user from opening the resource.
I want an icon or a message being displayed when you are trying to open a resource that is already in use,